# Render child component after data add to state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to the React and I'm working on a React Redux application. When I add a new item to the state I want to render the child component which shows item list. Currently item list showing in the state and new item also adding to that list (`mobileList`). How can I render child component when new item added to the state? Currently child component shows nothing.

Parent component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState ,ComponentState} from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Button, Container, Row, Col, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import uuid from "react-uuid";
import allActions from '../Actions/index'
import MobileList from './MobileList';

const MobileCreation = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const initialMobileState = {
    id: "",
    modelName: "",
    brand: "",
    year: "",
    price: "",
  };

  const [mobile, setMobile] = useState(initialMobileState);
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [submitSuccesful, setSubmitSuccesful] = useState(false);

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setMobile({ ...mobile, [name]: value });
  };

  const saveMobile = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSubmitted(true);

    if (mobile.modelName && mobile.brand && mobile.year && mobile.price) {
      var data = {
        Id: uuid(),
        ModelName: mobile.modelName,
        Brand: mobile.brand,
        Year: mobile.year,
        Price: mobile.price,
      };
    }

   dispatch(allActions.MobileActions.save(data));
   setSubmitted(false);
   setMobile(initialMobileState);
  };

  return (
      <>
    <Form onSubmit={saveMobile}>
      <Form.Group controlId="mobile.ModelName">
        <Form.Label>Model Name</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter model name"
          name="modelName"
          value={mobile.modelName}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        {submitted && !mobile.modelName && <div>Model name is required</div>}
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group controlId="mobile.Brand">
        <Form.Label>Brand Name</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter Brand name"
          name="brand"
          value={mobile.brand}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        {submitted && !mobile.brand && <div>Brand name is required</div>}
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group controlId="mobile.Year">
        <Form.Label>Year</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter year"
          name="year"
          value={mobile.year}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        {submitted && !mobile.year && <div>Year is required</div>}
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group controlId="mobile.Price">
        <Form.Label>Price</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter price"
          name="price"
          value={mobile.price}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        {submitted && !mobile.price && <div>Price is required</div>}
      </Form.Group>
      <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Form>
    <MobileList/>
    </>
  );
};

export default MobileCreation;
```

Child Component

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch ,} from "react-redux";
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table'

const MobileList = () => {
  const mobileList = useSelector((state) => state.mobileList);

  return (
    <>
      <Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Model Name</th>
            <th>Brand Name</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{mobileList ? 
             mobileList.map(function(item, i){
            <tr>
                <td>item.ModelName</td>
                <td>item.Brand</td>
                <td>item.Year</td>
                <td>item.Price</td>
            </tr>
            }) :
           <tr>
               <td>No data</td>
           </tr>
        
            }
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </>
  );
};

export default MobileList;
```

Reducer

```
const initialMobileListState = {
    mobileList:[]
}


const mobileReducer= (state = initialMobileListState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "SAVE":
            return {
                ...state,
                mobileList:[...state.mobileList, action.mobile]
            }
        case "FAIL":
            return state 
        default: 
            return state
    }
}

export default mobileReducer
```

[image]

Comment: As I see, your child component rendered in any case. And it will be updated automatically when state.mobileList will be updated.
Seems the problem is in how do you update the state. It includes how does work "allActions.MobileActions.save" and how do you update values in reducer.

Comment: I have updated the question with reducer code

Comment: I see you update reducer correctly. The question then is check that is it really updated when you submit the form?  Put some debugger there. And another question, is state.mobileList really correct path to retrieve data.

Comment: I have checked it with redux dev tools and it show the mobileList Items , I have added the image

Comment: Ok, and did you check that path correct? Isn't it smth like state.MobileReducer.mobileList?
If not, then I need a JS fiddle to see all code.

Comment: Thanks for the help Eugene , Issue sorted after state.mobileList changed to state.MobileReducer.mobileList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the wrong value in a selector.
You needed to use

```
state.MobileReducer.mobileList
```

instead of

```
state.mobileList
```